# drag drop and change parent of a div in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

In http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

If i drag a div to "`snaptarget`" div.
Will the dragged div be shown INSIDE it as its child element in the `DOM`?
I hit f12 on browser and saw the position cordinates changing as I drag but showing that the **parent** of that dragged,dropped div was unchanged.

I think same happens with droppable http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Is there a way to check and be sure?

**I do want this feature as I want to drag one div to another and later know the parent of that div.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dragged element is either duplicated or transplanted as a child of the drop target (depending on what you've selected for the [`helper` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper)).

To state this more explicitly, there will be a DOM node under the droppable element that contains the draggable element.

EDIT:

It appears I was mistaken. This isn't default behavior, but you could do something like this:

```
$(".target").droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    }
});
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/VTHcG/

Comment: @MasoodAhmad Are you dropping it into a [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) element?

Comment: works now. thanks. plus 1. Though here are some issues (on drag the size of dragged changes) 2. what about to redrage it to another div?  so there are now 2 parent divs (doppables) and one draggable that may enter either many times

Answer (score 4):

I got it working with Asad's help

http://jsfiddle.net/4bmT9/1/

and found this wonderful thing made by some one else

http://jsfiddle.net/l33r0y/yrLbE/48/

**JS:**

```
$('.dragme').draggable();
$('#drop, #source').droppable({
    drop:function(e, ui) {
        $(e.target).append($(ui.draggable).detach().css({'top':'', 'left':''}));
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="source" class="box">
    <div class="dragme">bacon</div>

</div>
<div id="drop" class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box { height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #333; }
.dragme { width:100%; margin:5px; border:1px solid #333; }
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/4bmT9/1/

Comment: Masood, you should accept the answer that works best, regardless of whether it is your own.

Comment: Nice thought, Just put reference to my answer in you answer if you like. You were the one who gave the idea. so accepting yours. :) . I would get upvotes if people like it. so doesnt matters.