# ui-sortable not working (for predefined DOM positions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Please see this demo [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/or6m2v4z/1/)

**Item 3** does not get sorted.How To make every element sort perfectly?

**Note :** Item 3 is `float:right` thats the need in project.
Acually in my project I have used DOM positions (eg:left:20px , right:10px) rather than float left or right.
If anyone can make this
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/or6m2v4z/1/) workable than it would be huge help.

What i want is all the elements should sort (specially item 3 which is not sorting).

What I tried is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6883L2gq/1/) .Which is not perfect.

**Explanation** :when user drags a element to left side of parent div and drops than the element sticks to left of div  .. if dragged to right it sticks to right. thats the reason i am using DOM positions. Now I have to make it sortable too.

Comment: what i tried is working . but on first sort it first rearranges according to DOM positions in code and than it sorts perfectly after first attempt.I want to sort perfectly on first attempt itself

Comment: Do you want the last item to be always `float:right`?

Comment: @Skatch I have added a explanation in the question . You will understand my need

Comment: Updated again, try now

Answer (score 1):

By having `float: right` on Item 3, you're explicitely telling the browser to position to the right hand side of everything else in the same block that is not styled with `float:right`.

If you have a look at the DOM in your browser's dev tools after having tried to move Item 3, you'll see that it has actually been repositioned.

Edit:

I guess this does what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/or6m2v4z/6/

Instead of having the `float` style on the items themselves, they've been wrapped inside two containers floating left and right respectively.
Using the sortable [connectWith](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith) option, both containers can be linked so that their contents can be moved freely among them.

The containers need minimum dimensions so they don't disappear if empty (that's also the reason I added the gray background).

Comment: I know sir. I know that . But thats the need of client. How to make my Project manager accept this fact :D  Is there any other alternative to make items stick to left and right of div (on dropping) . and than sort too :|

Comment: I have added a explanation in my question ,, you can know the exact need now

Comment: all my elements are in one parent div but

Comment: There'll be no proper solution if it's a hard requirement to have all items on the same div, since the problem is a matter of document structure and you're restricted to solving it with styling.
The only alternative I see is dynamically restructuring the list, i.e. using JavaScript after the document has loaded:
* Create the left and right containers
* Foreach item, move it into the correct container according to its float style.
It's not pretty, but it works with the input you're given and will cause way less headaches along the way than abusing styles.

Answer (score 1):

The sort works, it's the css that is causing you problems. Try this way:

https://jsfiddle.net/or6m2v4z/4/

What I changed:

```
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; float:left}
#sortable li:last-child {float:right}
```

And I also removed the inline styles :)

**EDIT**

I just read the explanation you provided, if you want to drop elements left or right, maybe you should use a left and a right container and try with the droppable function instead of sortable.

[drag drop and change parent of a div in dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904314/drag-drop-and-change-parent-of-a-div-in-dom)

**EDIT 2**

I did a little workaround for you. Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/or6m2v4z/5/

Comment: the fact is i want that css too .needed in step 1. sorting is step 2 ... and items can randomly be float right or left .

Comment: it checks if the item dropped is more or less than the half width of container. Not always correct but very useful.. can you please tell me if it can be possible for positions like left:20px or right:0px

Comment: Well, the ui.position parameter gives you only left and top, but you can calculate the right parameter with `container_width - (left + width)`. I don't know if you need a container width at all, or maybe body width, but you get the point. :)